# jqPivot- how do I just show the data rows and not summary headers?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqpivot

I am trying to build a jqPivot (sample jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/reckert/vqetvqoc/1/) 
I need a single row for with each of the X Dimensions in it, and then the values - what I am getting is

[image: Image of JS Fiddle results]

How can I remove the upper collapsing rows so I can get something more like:

[image]

I have tried both the trirand jqGrid and free.jqGrid and get similar results.
Here is the code I am using:

```
var mydata = [{
  "System": "Central Product Library (CPL)",
  "RFSTitle": "CPL - service support",
  "WorkRequest": "HBCBS00896187",
  "RFS": "40000",
  "PCR": "1",
  "EstimateType": "IE",
  "PHASE": "New",
  "Estimate": 10000.0,
  "BilledTo": null,
  "Lock": false,
  "CategoryID": 2,
  "Category": "BlueList",
  "Rate": 59.1600,
  "MonthEndDate": "2016-01-22T00:00:00",
  "MonthHours": 3750.000000000000,
  "MonthDollars": 221850.000000
}, {
  "System": "Central Product Library (CPL)",
  "RFSTitle": "CPL - service support",
  "WorkRequest": "HBCBS00896187",
  "RFS": "40000",
  "PCR": "1",
  "EstimateType": "IE",
  "PHASE": "New",
  "Estimate": 10000.0,
  "BilledTo": null,
  "Lock": false,
  "CategoryID": 2,
  "Category": "BlueList",
  "Rate": 59.1600,
  "MonthEndDate": "2016-02-26T00:00:00",
  "MonthHours": 6250.000000000000,
  "MonthDollars": 369750.000000
}, {
  "System": "Central Product Library (CPL)",
  "RFSTitle": "CPL - service support",
  "WorkRequest": "HBCBS00896187",
  "RFS": "40000",
  "PCR": "2",
  "EstimateType": "IE",
  "PHASE": "1",
  "Estimate": 2222.0,
  "BilledTo": null,
  "Lock": false,
  "CategoryID": 2,
  "Category": "BlueList",
  "Rate": 59.1600,
  "MonthEndDate": "2016-01-22T00:00:00",
  "MonthHours": 740.670000000000,
  "MonthDollars": 43817.850000
}, {
  "System": "Central Product Library (CPL)",
  "RFSTitle": "CPL - service support",
  "WorkRequest": "HBCBS00896187",
  "RFS": "40000",
  "PCR": "2",
  "EstimateType": "IE",
  "PHASE": "1",
  "Estimate": 2222.0,
  "BilledTo": null,
  "Lock": false,
  "CategoryID": 2,
  "Category": "BlueList",
  "Rate": 59.1600,
  "MonthEndDate": "2016-02-26T00:00:00",
  "MonthHours": 1234.450000000000,
  "MonthDollars": 73029.750000
}, {
  "System": "Central Product Library (CPL)",
  "RFSTitle": "CPL - service support",
  "WorkRequest": "HBCBS00896187",
  "RFS": "40000",
  "PCR": "2",
  "EstimateType": "IE",
  "PHASE": "1",
  "Estimate": 2222.0,
  "BilledTo": null,
  "Lock": false,
  "CategoryID": 2,
  "Category": "BlueList",
  "Rate": 59.1600,
  "MonthEndDate": "2016-03-25T00:00:00",
  "MonthHours": 246.890000000000,
  "MonthDollars": 14605.950000
}];


var grid = $("#grid");

grid.jqGrid('jqPivot',
  mydata, {
    xDimension: [

      {
        groupfield: false,
        groupSummary: false,
        width: 160,
        dataName: 'RFS',
        label: 'RFS'
      }, {
        isGroupField: false,
        groupSummary: false,
        width: 160,
        dataName: 'WorkRequest',
        label: 'WorkRequest'
      },

      {
        groupfield: false,
        groupSummary: false,
        width: 160,
        dataName: 'RFSTitle',
        label: 'Title'
      }, {
        groupfield: false,
        groupSummary: false,
        width: 160,
        dataName: 'Category',
        label: 'Category'
      }, {
        groupfield: false,
        groupSummary: false,
        width: 160,
        dataName: 'Phase',
        label: 'Phase'
      }, {
        groupfield: false,
        groupSummary: false,
        width: 160,
        dataName: 'Rate',
        label: 'Rate'
      },
    ],
    yDimension: [{
        dataName: 'MonthEndDate'
      }
      //,            { dataName: 'PCR' }
    ],
    aggregates: [{
      aggregator: 'sum',
      width: 160,
      member: 'MonthHours',
      label: "Hours"
    }, {
      aggregator: 'sum',
      width: 160,
      member: 'MonthDollars',
      label: "Dollars"
    }],
    groupSummary: false,
    colTotals: true
  },
  // grid options
  {
    groupingView: {
      hideFirstGroupCol: false,
      groupSummary: [false, false, false, false, false, false],
      groupSummaryPos: ["trailer", "trailer", "trailer", "trailer", "trailer", "trailer"],
    },
    pager: true,
    pager: "#MonthlyBillPivotPager",
    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    cmTemplate: {
      autoResizable: true
    },
    shrinkToFit: false,
    autoresizeOnLoad: true,
    autoResizing: {
      compact: true
    },
    caption: 'RFS Billing',
    hideFirstGroupCol: false
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code have small errors in the names of values of some properties or options. You use for example `groupSummaryPos` which contains non-existing values: `"trailer"`, but the only allows values are: `"header"` or `"footer"`. I removed just all unneeded properties. I'd recommend you to read [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/jqPivot-in-version-4.9) where I described the options of `jqPivot` used in free jqGrid.

The main problem, which you have is the problem with grouping of the data. The reason of the problem is the usage of wrong name of `PHASE` property. The source data contains the property, but you used `dataName: 'Phase'` (wrong case!!!):

```
{
    groupfield: false,
    groupSummary: false,
    width: 160,
    dataName: 'Phase',
    label: 'Phase'
}
```

To fix the problem you should change the item of `xDimension` to

```
{
    width: 80,
    dataName: 'PHASE',
    label: 'Phase'
}
```

Additionally I removed `autoresizeOnLoad: true`, because it don't use the texts from the column headers of the top levels.

You can see the results of grouping on the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/tcxv2o22/4/

[image]

Comment: I was hoping to also hide the tree so my output would be like i posted above.  I think I found one way to do it, though I don't know if its the 'best'.

Comment: I didn't realize I can't hit enter on comments - my updated method is to add CSS tags to hide the rows I don't want:  http://jsfiddle.net/reckert/vqetvqoc/3/

Comment: @RobertEckert: I don't understand what you want to implement. It seems to me that you want just have **no grouping**. You can use `grouping: false` option of jqGrid. See https://jsfiddle.net/tcxv2o22/5/ or https://jsfiddle.net/tcxv2o22/7/. Moreover you should clear understand that Free jqGrid, Guriddo jqGrid JS and old jqGrid 4.6.0 are different. I rewrote **full implementation of jqPivot** in free jqGrid. You can't mix the options from different jqGrid forks (see your demo)

Comment: @Oleg- Thanks those examples are exactly what I was looking for, I bounced around between the original jqGrid and the Guriddo one before I found yours, I just sent a donation to cover the time you just saved me :-).